# What is the development package for "gstreamer-player-1.0"

Tags: gstreamer, vala

According to valadoc, a package called [`gstreamer-player-1`](https://valadoc.org/gstreamer-player-1.0/index.htm) exists. However, I can't find a corresponding package in the
[ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev.  I found it by [searching for the pkg-config file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gstreamer-player-1.0.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any).

Comment: service click for the sources - https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/1.22.2/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst-libs/gst/player/meson.build?ref_type=tags#L2 .. unclear as to why it's attributed to the "bad" plugins